# Octave uigetfile() not returning full path of file

Tags: path, octave

I'm using `uigetfile()` in octave to select an image file from directory, but it's not returning the full path. Why?

Here's an example in octave:

```
  [fname, fpath, fltindx] = uigetfile();
  filename = [fpath, fname];     % Get the full path of the file
  load(filename);                % hand_data is now loaded
```

The results should be:

```
fname = 'trview_h_data.mat';
fpath = '/home/trink/en/JeffTrinkle/';

uigetfile() returns the correct file name, but the last subdirectory of the path is missing.  Here's what is returned.
fpath = '/home/trink/en/';
```

For the past two years, this code worked. The problem described started after upgrading to the most recent version of octave.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s code that used to work but doesn’t any more, then you might have a regression bug. Look through the release notes to see if this was intended (seems unlikely though). If not, submit a bug to Ocrave’s issue tracker. There’s not much people here can do for you, other than tell you to downgrade until the bug is fixed.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this issue in v8.4.0 on windows or with a recent build (10.0.0) on ubuntu.  I don't have 8.4.0 on a linux distro though (i assume that's what you mean by latest version).  please do go to https://bugs.octave.org and submit a report detailing which OS and versions you saw different results in. there have been some changes in filepath handling, but i thought those were ironed out before and the issues were only really on windows and paths with non-ascii characters.

Comment: Thanks Cris for your comments.  I'll do some more testing on different builds and then sent off a message to octave if I still can't get this to work.

Comment: Just adding I can't reproduce either; octave 8.4.0, linux mint 21.2. As a side-note, concatenating the strings is not a robust way of creating the full file; use the `fullfile` command instead. (probably unrelated to your bug though). Also, the `make_absolute_filename` and `canonicalize_file_name` functions may be useful, especially if dealing with symlinks.

Comment: Thank you Tasos.  I just found fullfile yesterday and was trying it out.  Thanks for the pointers tomake_absolute_filename and canonicalize_file_name.